# "App not installed" error on almost every device I try my Unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I made a very simple 2d game for android.

Build was success with 0 errors. I uploaded the .apk file to my drive. From there I downloaded it to my HUAWEI P8 (Android 6.0) old phone. 
Everythings works.

I've downloaded it again to a LENOVO (Android 9.0).

I got "App not installed" error with nothing else. I tried several Android emulators. On every one of them I got "App not installed" error. On one of them I got "Your phone is not compatible" beside the other error and that's it.

Things I've tried:

- Turning off Play Protect (from Google Play)
- Allowing apps from untrusted sources
- Cleaning more free space
- Setting "Install Location" to Automatic (from Player settings)
- Downloading/importing the .apk from somewhere else
- Setting Android 9.0 as a Target version
- Checking ARMv7 too as a Target architecture

Comment: See logcat for error messages

Comment: @stubborn Can you share the error log and gradle config? Also can you check with a release apk?

Comment: No errors found in the logs, tried with signed/unsigned apk too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time wondering and playing with the settings I think its working now. Here are some of my options in the Player settings:

> Scripting backend: IL2CPP
>
> Api compatibility level: .NET Standard 2.0
>
> Target Architectures: ARMv7, ARM64, x86 (deprecated).
>
> Install location: Automatic
>
> Write Permission: Internal

Beside the things I've written in the question I also checked all three architectures as targets (even the deprecated one). I've connected the tablet with USB in order to use Build and Run option and didn't see any error (when I later changed target architectures a error told me that I should target ARMv7 too) and everything worked as expected.

I later uploaded it to my drive again and installed it from there too.

I've tried & tested in emulators too (I think the deprecated architecture is used).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had Shared the steps, It will definitely resolve the issue regarding Unity App Not Installed

1. Check is you bundle identifier is same with previous build
2. PlayerSettings > Enable build il2cpp Armv7 and 64bit build and donot split the build
3. Assign the keystore and assign password
4. Set the player setting SDK Card to Automatic
5. Make Sure your previous build is assigned with same keystore
6. Target Api Level should be Equal or greater than previous one